# Displaying an image from a URL returned by an API

Tags: php, html, xml, zillow

I am making an API call that should return something like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Chart:chart xmlns:Chart="http://www.zillow.com/vstatic/3/static/xsd/Chart.xsd">
    <request>
        <zpid>48749425</zpid> 
        <unit-type>percent</unit-type> 
        <width>300</width> 
        <height>150</height> 
    </request>
    <message>
        <text>Request successfully processed</text> 
        <code>0</code> 
    </message>
    <response>
        <url>http://www.zillow.com/app?chartDuration=1year&chartType=partner&height=150&      page=webservice%2FGetChart&service=chart&showPercent=true&width=300&zpid=48749425</url> 
    </response>
</Chart:chart>
```

And what I need is to display the chart image that is at the returned URL, but how do I do that?!?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [simple_xml](http://php.net/simple_xml):

```
$x = simplxml_load_string($xml);
echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($x->response->url) . '">';
```

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks for responding.  
Could not get that to work with load_string, but I removed the htmlspecialchars() and changed to load_file  and it worked.  Can you tell me why? :)
THanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Given the XML data in a variable $xml, you could parse it and output an `<img>` tag using [XMLDOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) functions:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);


$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("url");
if ($nodes->length>0)
{
    $node=$nodes->item(0);
    $url=htmlentities($node->nodeValue);

    echo "<img src=\"$url\">";
}
```

You could also use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('Chart/response/url');
if ($nodes->length>0)
{
    $node=$nodes->item(0);
    $url=htmlentities($node->nodeValue);

    echo "<img src=\"$url\">";
}
```

There is also [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) too

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$url = htmlentities($doc->response->url);
echo "<img src=\"$url\">";
```

**Note that the XML you posted is invalid** - the `&` characters in the URL should be `&amp;` for any of these XMLDOM methods to work properly. But this at least illustrates how to work with XML "properly"

So, a simpler approach would be to just rip out the url with a regex

```
if (preg_match('{<url>(.*?)</url>}', $xml, $matches))
{
     $url=htmlentities($matches[1]);
     echo "<img src=\"$url\">";
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks guys. The XML I posted I copied from their API example output... I am brand new to XML obviously, :)
Question though, where you both are using $xml up there, does that mean the API call?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for getting me going the right way.  I am not sure why I could not get it to work with the load_string function..?

This is what I used and it worked, do you know why?

```
<?php
$xml = 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetChart.htm?zws-id=******&unit-type=percent&
zpid='.$title->zpid.'&width=300&height=150';
$chart = simplexml_load_file($xml);
echo '<img src="' .$x->chart->url . '">';
?>
```